# Apache returns page with wrong mime type

Tags: apache, types, mime

I have a web app deployed on Tomcat 7 (on port 8080) and an Apache server (on port 80) in front of it, on Linux. When accessing the app on 8080, everything works fine. Otherwise, on port 80, the application behaves strange: when I make the same request (access the same link) several times, sometimes the response (the jsp page translated as HTML) is returned with content-type "application/octet-stream", as file to be downloaded.

If I open the downloaded file with notepad, there are a bunch of lines at the beginning with meaningless characters, followed by the response header and then my html page.

```
  <code>  
..•éb©®ùG.....< more nonsens >.......1Óä£ýÙw+ÊIñãðÇÿHTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2013 09:23:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Linux/SUSE)
Content-Language: ro
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

1ff8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
...<the rest of my html page>
</code>
```

It would seem as Apache throws an error, but the logs are clean (both Apache logs and mod_jk logs).

I appreciate any help. 


Thanks!


Tekin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: Avast Antivirus (the free version) silently messes with the response, which in turn brings another problem: why does it think it is a threat when accessing the site on port 80, but doesn't do anything when accessing the Tomcat directly on port 8080?

Comment: Why do you think that antivirus is causing this issue. Any proof of that?

Comment: Yes. And I also found the module causing the problem: if I turn off the Web Shield from Avast, everything works. Also, this problem appears on only one other computer, which also has Avast installed on it. Other computers didn't manifest this problem.

Comment: Ok, The port problem is maybe because port 80 is a standard HTTP port, that is why all the traffic going through port 80 is subject to check. Whereas, tomcat port (8080, or any other) is a application port.

Comment: Actually, the web shield checks port 8080 as well. To clarify, web shield doesn't find any threats on my web site. The site is: www.scanromcopiers.ro , maybe it helps. Click any icon a few times shows the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Not able to replicate it, what icons are you talking about. Anyways, check if you are setting correct content type in response object or not.

Comment: I checked. The content type is set to "text/html". For example, clicking the logo (the big S) on the top-left corner, downloads a file. Do you have Avast installed? My version is 6.0.1483. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have to completely turn off the Avast firewall and most of the garbage shields, if not the page does not load or reload and the little circle just goes around and around and around for ever or until it times out.

I discovered that it was Avast causing my problems by turning the damn thing off.  Turn it off and it works. It interferes with my javascript etc.

Also I can't sign into my site in two browsers.

I would use Linux instead of windows for web development however I love my Adobe Fireworks and other pieces of software, plus I absolutely have to have IE to test the site on.  So in order to develop and test my site I have to not have security.  I won't be buying avast again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are getting is that you are issuing a http 1.1 call and that version supports chunking of large pieces of data. 
The key piece of output you are getting is:

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

1ff8

etc.
You obviously don't expect that nor do you want to interpret it - therefore you should issue a HTTP 1.0 request.